# Variable initialisation not happening everywhere on certain platforms

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, ubuntu, redhat

I have a program that I built for RHEL5 32 bit and ubuntu10 64 bit (c++ qt4.6).  When I run the program on ubuntu, all the variables are initialized without me needing to code this initialization.  But When I run the program on RHEL, some of the variables are not initialized, I have noticed that they are mostly integer type and the typicial values are around 154280152. The funny thing is that it just happens in a few classes.  How can this be?

update: here is a snippet of code, it is the header of one of the classes where this is happening(sorry for the layout I am looking into that right now):



 `#ifndef FCP_CONFIG_H

 #define FCP_CONFIG_H

 #include "ui_fcpConfig.h"
 #include 

 #include "fpsengine.h"

 #include "fcp_cfg_delegate.h"

 #define SET_COL 3

 #define GLOBAL_KEY_COL 2

     #define LOCAL_KEY_COL 1

    #define ENABLE_COL 0

    namespace Ui

    {

        class fcpConfig;

    }`

```
class fcpConfig : public QWidget  
{  
Q_OBJECT  

public:  
fcpConfig(QWidget *parent, FPSengine * FPS);  
Ui::fcpConfigForm ui;  
void setupFcpCfg();  

private:  
QWidget * myParent;  
FPSengine * myFPS;  

fcpCfgDelegate delegate;  
QList<QSpinBox*>failOrderList;  
QList<QRadioButton*>primaryList;  

int numFCP;  
QList<int>numFcpInEachSet;  
int currentSet;  

void updateSets();
void refreshFailorderDuringUserEdit(int fcpPos);
QSignalMapper * signalMapper;
QMutex mutex;
void sendSysStatusMsgAndPopup(QString msg);
int curSet;   //the connected Fcp's Set  

private slots:  

void updateFcpFailOrderSpinBox(int absPos);
void on_twFCP_cellClicked( int row, int column );
void on_buttonBox_clicked(QAbstractButton* button);

private:  
template <class T>  
    void buildObjList(QObject * location,QList<T> *cmdEleList,QString objName, int numObj){  
        T pCmdEle;  
        cmdEleList->clear();  
        for(int i=0;i<numObj;i++){  
            pCmdEle = location->findChild<T>(objName+QString("%1").arg(i+1));  
            cmdEleList->append(pCmdEle);  
        }  
    }  

//used to send SysStatus and popuMsg when number of active Fcps in Set not 1  
QString activeList;  //build a string representing Fcp numbers that are active.  
int iNumActive;  
};  
#endif // FCP_CONFIG_H
```

Comment: Post your code, it's very difficult to help otherwise.

Comment: Uninitialized variables can contain *anything*. It may always be zero on certain platforms, but your code should never count on that.

Comment: Not every question on SO is from a small project. Boil it down to a small reproducer, post the code, them you will most likely get more meaningful answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Different compilers do different things. **The standard doesn't state that all variables should be initialized automatically**, so many compilers don't. This means they are typically filled with garbage. Sometimes you luck out and get a block of zeros, but it's rare. Don't count on it.

Comment: Always, always, always initialize variables. Then, even if your code is incorrect, at least it is also consistent.

Comment: Initialize variables! Your life may depend on it.

Comment: @yan The standard doesn't state that it must be random either.

Comment: @yan: It's a good practice to initialize all variables from the start.

Comment: @yan What kind of abnormal behavior do you imagine an uninitialized variable could actually help you detect? I can't think of a case where using the value of an uninitialized variable wouldn't be a problem in its own right and in need of being solved before anything else useful could be accomplished with it.

Comment: @TheUndeadFish this is exactly the reason why I ended up asking this question.  For example: if(var<MAX && var> MIN) {assign your variable}  else {do not assign your variable but you still should}  otherwise I would of used an initialized value that is not necessarily the value I want.

Comment: @yan bellavance: I didn't say anything about random events. I said some compilers will initialize some things, others won't. Don't be misled by that block of zeros comment.